# Getting Error while requesting READ_CONTACTS permission Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

i am trying to get READ_CONTACTS permission Android M and on calling:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
```

app crash with following exception:

```
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.computePermissionGrantState(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:293)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.updateDefaultResults(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:343)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.onCreate(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:100)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
05-12 17:08:24.578: E/AndroidRuntime(2846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

I have also specified `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` in the Manifest file.

Comment: Are you sure that the code in your question is what is generating this stack trace? My interpretation of that stack trace would suggest that perhaps you are accidentally calling `requestPermissions()` with a `null` `String[]`.

Comment: Do you have the permission listed in the correct place in the manifest? That is, outside of the `<application>` tags.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks Man, i accidently put it inside Application tag, it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for `GrantPermissionsActivity`, the only place in the `computePermissionGrantState()` method that you could get a `NullPointerException` from an `Attempt to get length of null array` is in this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < callingPackageInfo.requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
```

Since you've stated that you have indeed listed the `READ_CONTACTS` permission in the manifest, it would follow that it's just in the wrong place, and is effectively not there. Ensuring that the `<uses-permission>` element is outside of the `<application>` tags solves the problem.

Comment: thanks Man, i accidently put it inside Application tag, it's working now.

Comment: thought the exception should be telling this, it's very difficult to understand the issue with current stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if they'd check for that, and throw an `Exception` with an appropriate message, but c'est la vie. Cheers!